# Iteration of list (length n) to contain every possible variation of a set X where n is larger than len(unique(X))

Tags: python, iteration

`itertools.permutation(iterate, r)` provides a way to provide a set of permutations of either length `r` or `len(iterate)`. However it does not work if -

r > `len(iterate)`

Take this example.

`list(intertools.permutation([0, 1, 2]))` returns...

`[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]`

This is expected.

But lets say that we would like r to be larger than the length of the iterate. i.e. if you iterate a set [0, 1, 2] over a length of 4 you would hope to get this sort of answer as below.

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 1]
 [0, 0, 0, 2]
 [0, 0, 1, 1]
 [0, 0, 1, 2]
 ...
 [2, 2, 1, 2]
 [2, 2, 2, 0]
 [2, 2, 2, 1]
 [2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

however when you try `list(itertools.permutation([0, 1, 2], 4))` it returns `[]` i.e. empty

If anyone knows of a way to do this please tell me.

Comment: If `len(iterate)` is `l`, and if `r` > `l`, how many permutations do you expect to be produced?

Comment: These are not permutations. You're looking for a cartesian product.

Comment: If so, I think there is a numpy primitive for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

In your case you could use `list(itertools.product(range(3), repeat=4))`

Comment: itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1) is the prototype of the function, as it appears in the Python documentation. Added an example for clarification.